# change existing Winform to wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way i can change my existing winform app to WPF,i had used c#.net and SQL Server 2005, I am a first timer in WPF, please consider before answering.

thanks

Comment: No - it's a complete shift in paradigm. Any "converter" is going to be defeating the point of switching to WPF.

Comment: Just a suggestion - if you're thinking this way, you obviously don't understand WPF well.  I'd recommend reading my series on migrating from Windows Forms to WPF here: http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Comment: @ReedCopsey +1 for the link - can't wait to set aside some time to read this.

Answer (score 6):

No - there is no "automatic" way to switch - nor would you want to do so.

While it's possible to write WPF in a manner very similar to Windows Forms, you typically do not want to do so.  It really defeats the purpose of changing.  The advantages of WPF really come into play when you take advantage of Xaml and data binding to their fullest extent, which wouldn't happen with an automatic conversion.

That being said, it's always possible to start writing some of your new user interfaces in WPF, and still use them within the existing Windows Forms project (via `ElementHost`).  This allows a *transition* to WPF, without having to "convert" at once.

Any application logic which is properly decoupled can be used from both Windows Forms and WPF, as is - so the only thing that has to change is the portion of your application tied to the user interface.

Comment: Basically i need to change UI, like sliding effect ,and doing it on Winform makes it slow hence its not smooth, so I have researched that WPF support such kind of UIs and its faster, is this correct ?

Comment: @user1737641 Yes - WPF provides quite a bit more control and flexibility if you want to make better user interfaces.  However, it is a lot more than just that - and really works well if you think about it a bit differently than Windows Forms.  It's really a completely different way to approach user interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project structure, WPF is all about UI. If you've a layered solution you can simply change its UI from WinForm to WPF, but There is no automatically way to do that, You have to rewrite your UI.

Comment: Can you please explain "layered solution"

Comment: @user1737641: Separating your UI (visual layer) from your back-end model (model layer).